# Gerar Boleto Itau a partir de um arquivo de remessa que esta em .txt

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso Gerar Boleto Itau PDF a partir de um arquivo de remessa que esta em .txt algumas sugestões para desenvolver a aplicação ?

Comment: Utilize a biblioteca boleto net https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet

Comment: Poderia me ajudar a encontrar o que vou precisar nesse projeto do git pois ele é enorme, você ja trabalhou com ele ?@L.Falousk

Comment: Acredito que você vai ter que estudar um pouco a biblioteca, eles tem alguns exemplos feitos lá, e eu nunca mexi com essa biblioteca.

Answer (score 1):

A muito tempo atrás fiz algo parecido utilizando o projeto [boleto.Net](https://github.com/boletonet) .

Você pode baixar e adicionar as referências a seu projeto ou então você pode obter através do Nuget:

> Install-Package Boleto.Net

Após isso adicione a biblioteca em seu projeto.

```
using BoletoNet;     //referência ao componente Boleto.Net
```

Não vou entrar em detalhes de como vai capturar os dados do arquivo .txt pois não sei em qual formato ele está, sugiro que use algo como csv.
Para isso você pode utilizar um Filestream, converter em matriz e etc.

Existem várias formas de fazer isso.

Partindo do princípio que o arquivo .txt já foi lido, pode-se utilizar o gerador de boletos assim:

```
protected void gerarBoletoItau()
    {
         // Preenche todos os campos necessários para criação do boleto - Substitua pelos valores vindos do arquivo txt.
        string vencimento = "18/08/2018";
        String valorBoleto = "50000";
        String numeroDocumento = "B20005446";

         // Cedente - substitua pelos valores vindos do arquivo txt
        String cedente_codigo = "1111111"; /
        String cedente_nossoNumeroBoleto = "22222222";
        String cedente_cpfCnpj = "123.456.789-01";
        String cedente_nome = "NOME DO CEDENTE.";
        String cedente_agencia = "1000";
        String cedente_conta = "22507";
        String cedente_digitoConta = "6";

         // Sacado -  substitua pelos valores vindos do arquivo txt
        String sacado_cpfCnpj = "000.000.000-00";
        String sacado_nome = "NOME DO SACADO";
        String sacado_endereco = "ENDEREÇO DO SACADO";
        String sacado_bairro = "BAIRRO DO SACADO";
        String sacado_cidade = "CIDADE DO SACADO";
        String sacado_cep = "CEP SACADO";
        String sacado_uf = "UF SACADO";

        // cria o objeto cedente 
        Cedente cedente = new Cedente(cedente_cpfCnpj,
        cedente_nome,
        cedente_agencia,
        cedente_conta,
        cedente_digitoConta);
        cedente.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(cedente_codigo);

        // cria parte do boleto
        Boleto boleto = new Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(vencimento),
                                                                Convert.ToDouble(valorBoleto),
                                                                "109",
                                                                cedente_nossoNumeroBoleto,
                                                                cedente);
        boleto.NumeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;

        // cria o objeto sacado
        Sacado sacado = new Sacado(sacado_cpfCnpj, sacado_nome);
        boleto.Sacado = sacado;
        boleto.Sacado.Endereco.End = sacado_endereco;
        boleto.Sacado.Endereco.Bairro = sacado_bairro;
        boleto.Sacado.Endereco.Cidade = sacado_cidade;
        boleto.Sacado.Endereco.CEP = sacado_cep;
        boleto.Sacado.Endereco.UF = sacado_uf;

        // Adiciona instruções
        Instrucao_Itau instrucao = new Instrucao_Itau();
        instrucao.Descricao = "Não Receber após o vencimento"; // Instrução padrão Itau

        // Adiciona as intruções ao boleto
        boleto.Instrucoes.Add(instrucao);
        EspecieDocumento_Itau especie = new EspecieDocumento_Itau(99);
        boleto.EspecieDocumento = especie;

        // Cria o boleto bancário final
        BoletoBancario boleto_bancario = new BoletoBancario();
        boleto_bancario.CodigoBanco = 341; // código do itau
        boleto_bancario.Boleto = boleto;
        boleto_bancario.MostrarCodigoCarteira = true;
        boleto_bancario.Boleto.Valida();

        boleto_bancario.MostrarComprovanteEntrega = true;
        // boleto criado - adicione abaixo o que deseja fazer com boleto: Imprimir, enviar, exibir, etc...


      }
```

Acredito que ainda funcione.